# File copying using ftw()

Tags: c

Below code lists out all files in a directory, can somebody tell me how to copy these files/directory to another location provided using command line argument.
I want to return the name from the list function, the problem is ftw(,list,) takes the return type as int. Since name char, how can i return it?

```
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<string.h>

int list(const char *name, const struct stat *status, int type);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 if(argc == 1)
  ftw(".", list, 1);
 else
  ftw(argv[1], list, 1);

 return 0;
}

int list(const char *name, const struct stat *status, int type) {
 if(type == FTW_NS)
  return 0;

 if(type == FTW_F)


 if(type == FTW_D && strcmp(".", name) != 0)


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: We are not a codding service your question is too broad.

Comment: Can you update your question for what kind of copy you would like? Shallow or deep? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Where do you want to copy the file to?  How do you copy a file given the source name? Show us the code you'd use to copy a file, and then ensure you call it in the appropriate part of the `list()` function, and … well, by then you've solved the problem.

Comment: Use standards C-functions `"system(const char *)"` or exec functions `execl(const char *, const char*)`, `execlp(const char *, const char*)` etc ... to execute linux shell commands in C code. Take a look at this linux manual page http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/exec.3.html

Comment: @shamba Are you seriously suggesting calling `system` to do something as trivial as copying a file. Even if we forget the security issues for a moment, why would you spawn a separate process just for copying a file?